# Unable to connect to oracle via Pentaho. 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, pentaho

Hi I've just installed Pentaho Data Integration v. 5.01 and I'm trying to connect to a database. However, I'm unable to test the connection as I get the error (pasted below).

I have JDK 1.7 installed on the system as well, however I can't seem to locate ojdbc14.jar anywhere.

I downloaded that and pasted it in pentaho's \lib folder but I still get the same error.

Any solutions to this problem?

```
Error connecting to database [test] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver


    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:415)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:353)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:306)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:294)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:84)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2459)
    at org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:541)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:139)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulComponent.invoke(AbstractXulComponent.java:123)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton.access$500(SwtButton.java:26)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtButton$4.widgetSelected(SwtButton.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:796)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:375)
    at org.pentaho.ui.xul.swt.tags.SwtDialog.show(SwtDialog.java:301)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:115)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.database.dialog.DatabaseDialog.open(DatabaseDialog.java:62)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:493)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.delegates.SpoonDBDelegate.newConnection(SpoonDBDelegate.java:478)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.doubleClickedInTree(Spoon.java:2885)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.access$2300(Spoon.java:332)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon$27.widgetDefaultSelected(Spoon.java:5657)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1227)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7368)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8673)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Driver class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' could not be found, make sure the 'Oracle' driver (jar file) is installed.
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:474)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:399)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connectUsingClass(Database.java:467)
    ... 46 more
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my setup. I had this problem and managed to fix it as follows.

I have SQLDeveloper running on my machine and it works OK, even under VPN. However, I was running Spoon and noticed that it wouldn't work if I use VPN.

I have tried to put Oracle JDBC drivers shipped with SQLDeveloper into Pentaho. That didn't work.

However, I noticed that one big difference between SQLDeveloper and Spoon is that they use different
Java runtimes and JDBC Oracle drivers! In particular, my version of SQLDeveloper is running on 32-bit JRE version 1.6.0_11, whereas my system-wide JDK is 64-bit version 1.7.0_03.

I have found the JDBC drivers that SQLDeveloper uses and used them as a replacement for the driver that is shipped with Spoon -- *no change*.

Then I retargeted Spoon to use the Java runtime used by SQLDeveloper.

I set two environment variables: PENTAHO_JAVA and PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME -- and it works OK now!

For reference, here are my envvars:

```
PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\opt\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe
PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=c:\opt\sqldeveloper\jdk\jre\
```

If that is relevant, I am on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I had found a work around. I already had a running version of Pentaho 4.1.0 on my system. It was 5.0.1 that was causing the problem.

So what I did was, I copied all the /lib* folders from 4.1 and pasted it in the same location of 5.0.1. And it worked!

The next time this happens, I'll try your method!

Answer (score 23):

Try placing the odbc jar file (eg: *ojdbc5-11.1.0.7.0.jar*) inside the "data-integration/**lib**" directory of your installation. Don't forget to restart Pentaho to make it work.

Comment: More details: http://www.knowpentaho.com/2013/12/pentaho-common-errors-driver-class.html

Answer (score 7):

**1**. First go to Oracle Site:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

**2**. Download 1 file: ojdbc6.jar
(2,739,670 bytes) - (SHA1 Checksum: a483a046eee2f404d864a6ff5b09dc0e1be3fe6c)
Classes for use with JDK 1.6. It contains the JDBC driver classes except classes for NLS support in Oracle Object and Collection types.

**3**. Copy it into Pentaho folder: C:\Program Files\Pentaho\data-integration\lib

**4**. Close Spoon if it is open and re-open again. (*transferred from the comment of @mishkin - thanks him*)

That works on my Windows 7 X64 Pro with latest Pentaho 5.3 Stable.

Comment: 4. close Spoon if it is open and re-open again. this was the missing step for me

Answer (score 2):

In Pentaho version 6.0 put the driver (ojdbc6.jar) in: "PentahoInstallation"\design-tools\data-integration\lib and restart the Data Integration ide.

Answer (score 1):

See, guys we doesn't need all these stuff. We need to paste oracle jdbc driver (ojdbc6.jar) in the following location.

1. C:\Program Files\pentaho\design-tools\report-designer\lib\jdbc
2. C:\Program Files\pentaho\design-tools\data-integration\lib
3. C:\Program Files\pentaho\design-tools\aggregation-designer\lib
4. C:\Program Files\pentaho\design-tools\schema-workbench\lib

Answer (score 0):

try to put ojdbc driver in libext/JDBC in your PDI path (location)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the jar on tomcat library folder, then restart Pentaho.

Should be here `.../biserver-ce-6.0.0.0-353/biserver-ce/tomcat/lib`

There are already some drivers here.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by selecting Oralce Native connection > Hostname as Ip address of DB server > instead of SN00XXXX I had used DB00XXX name for the Database name.

I hope this works for such issues with oracle connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was in **Report designer**

The fix: only copy **ojdbc14.jar** to

**\prd-ce-5.0.1-stable\report-designer\lib**

and restart the tool.